# How to test Language DLLs?

Tags: testing, dll, translation

Our application offer the user to display different languages if they have the approppriate Language DLL (say German.DLL, French.DLL, even Chinese.DLL).

We have functional test to verify that those DLLs enable the right options in a Combobox and that choosing them will actually translate strings in the UI.

I would like to know options to test this translation dll's more in depth, maybe ensuring that all the characters in the selected langauge (and in the file) can be correctly displayed, or that the internal structure of the DLL is consistent, there are no strings exceeding the limits that are expected of them, etc...

Any suggestions on what to test and how to test it?
Does anyone know specific problems that may arise and we should check?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and test for what you want out of the DLL.  Without many details on what you're doing you should aim for tests which are of the following type.

Ensure that all the resources/strings are in the DLL.

Ensure that resources/strings can be retrieved.

Ensure that the resources/strings are correct.